# Is it possible to generate items inside Flowable.generate() lazily?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a database which can be updated while the `RxJava` chain in the middle of its work.

The `RxJava` chain looks like this:

```
Flowable.generate(/*Query database for 1 item*/)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .concatMap(/*Mapping*/)
        .concatMap(/*Mapping*/)
        .subscribe(/*Consumers*/)
```

The database can be updated while the `RxJava` chain in the middle of processing the emission. So `Flowable.generate()` should request one item at a time and wait until onNext() consumer is finished and only after this query next item.

Is it possible to query items inside Flowable.generate() lazily only after onNext is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `generate` will generate items based on downstream demand. If you can control the demand, you can control when and how many items are generated. However, most of the time, especially with those `concatMap`s, you won't have such fine control. The alternative is to create a feedback loop via a subject/processor and map its item to the asynchronous querying of the database:

```java
FlowableProcessor<Integer> processor = PublishProcessor.<Integer>create().toSerialized();

processor
.concatMap(_ -> 
   getNextSingleItemAsync().subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
)
.concatMap(/*Mapping*/)
.concatMap(/*Mapping*/)
.subscribe(item -> {
    /* Process item. */

    // get to the next item
    processor.onNext(1);
});

processor.onNext(0); // start the loop
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if it's impossible to have `processor` and `onNext` consumer in the same place? For example, if the chain encapsulated in some method that returns `Flowable<Item>`. In this case, we will have no access to `processor` and will subscribe outside the class that holds `processor`.

Comment: You'd have to write an operator that exposes the `request()` call in a way that you can call it from within the end consumer. Also this operator has to suppress requests from its immediate downstream to avoid interference.